# BAT file to read many .txt files in the folder and merge them into .csv file and add part of the file name to the front of each line

Tags: batch-file

I want my code to read every .txt file and add the first 6 numbers of the file name to the front of the line... I have the first part of the code set up and I know how the second part needs to look I just don`t know how to merge them..

```
@echooff
del Build_count.csv
for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (%%a) do echo %%a,%%b >> Build_count.csv

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist List.cvs del List.cvs
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    set fn=%%~na
    set fn=!fn:~0,6!
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just appending one code to the other doesn't help you. You need to insert the second snippet into the first loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
  set "fn=%%~na"
  for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (%%a) do (
    echo !fn:~0,6!,%%b 
  )
))>Build_count.csv
```

For every matching file extract the desired string, then in another loop read every line and write the string plus the line. Redirect the whole thing to the destination file in one go (that's much faster than opening the file, finding the end, adding a line and closing the file again for each and every line). Deleting it beforehand isn't necessary, because the code overwrites the file anyway.

Note: the `for /f` loop as it stands now ignores empty lines and lines starting with a `;`. Adaptions are necessary if that's a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is eaxctly what I kept not been able to figure out... I wrote a very similar thing but did not have the whole for block enveloped in () . I think maybe that is why it was not working. Once again, thank you!!!

Comment: `the whole for block enveloped in ()` is only to be able to redirect the whole output in one go. It works exactly the same when you remove the redirection and outer `()` (just that it prints on the screen instead of a file), so the block itself wasn't your problem.